# iis7 bandwith throttling for downloads via iis media services?

Tags: iis-7, bandwidth, rate-limiting

I am looking after a sever that is managing the downloads of software updates released by the company where I work. The throttle in IIS7 seems to limit the total rate and not the rate each individual download gets. I was thnking on installing media services, adding .zip as a type and then throttling the individual connection rate based on what I read.

Is this how this sort of thing is done with IIS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this walk through recently that provides step by step instructions on how to do this:

[bit rate throttling using media services](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/148/bit-rate-throttling-configuration-walkthrough/)